# Pass IEnumerable variable to view in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, checkbox, ienumerable

I speak a little English. I try to ask my question.

I have a model. it's name Product.cs

```
  Product
  {
    public int TypeId { get; set; }/*these are at the same time field of Type Table*/
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public int TradeMarkId { get; set; }/*at the same time field of TradeMark Table*/
    public string TradeMarkName { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }/*at the same time field of TProduct Table*/
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int TId { get; set; }
    public int TMId { get; set; }

    public List<TypeProduct> typeList { get; set; }
  }
```

My controller page

```
  My controller 
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult TradeMarkProduckAdd()
  {
    Product product = new Product();
    TypeList typeList = new TypeList();
    product = typeList.TypeListOf(product);
    return View(product);//"This doesn't work"            
  }
```

it says a type error
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TypeMark.Models.Product', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TypeMark.Models.Product]'.

when I got this error I changed the **return View(product);** to 
**return View((IEnumerable)product);** but it didnt work again.

view page

```
    @using TypeTradeMark.Models
    @model IEnumerable<Product>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      @foreach(var item in Model as List<Product>)
      {                              
        @item.ProductName
        @item.??//checkbox for every record      
        @item.??//dropdownlist for trademarks      
      }    
    }
```

TypeList class

```
    TypeList class

    public class TypeList
    {
      VtDataContext Vt = new VtDataContext();
      public Product TypeListOf(Product typeListOf)
      {          
        var query = (from c in Vt.Types select c);
        typeListOf.typeList=new List<Type>(query.ToList());
        return typeListof;
      }
    }
```

my tables

```
    Type : TypeId, TypeName
    TradeMark : TradeMarkId,TradeMarkName
    TProduct : ProductId,ProductName,TId,TMId//TId relation with TypeId, TMId relation with TradeMarkId
```

I couldnt solve the problem Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Your model is kind'a strange... How do you create database?? Do U have to support already existed db, or do you create it by yourself?

Comment: I create the database. is it wrong?

Comment: No, it's not wrong, but I think your model is wrong. If I understand you correctly... U have Such objects: product, trademark and product type. One product has one trademark, and several types. For example some aSer notebook has "aSer" trademark an belongs to such product types as computer technics, office technics, technics, notebooks etc. Am I right?

Comment: yes aSer is tradeMark, computer is Type, aSer computer is a Tproduct table record. my model may be wrong but I want to use  more than one table field of my database in a model. I cant use one table in a model. for example I cant use @model TradeMark. because in my view I use trademark name and  Product Name and Type name.

Answer (score 1):

You view expect list of `Product` type objects, see (`@model IEnumerable<Product>`).

Try to use something like this:

```
return View(new List<Product> { product, product2 })
```

Comment: thanks, but there is a place I dont understand. return View(product); product is already a list(I think) isnt it? my list(means product) is from database. so how can I create a new list in return view

Comment: You view is strongly-typed (you made this by using @model). If you want your view to accept one product just drop IEnumerable, use `@model Product`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create an interface like so:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

Change your controller to use this IEnumerable interface instead of the class Product.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you have declared @model IEnumerable which means this view is strongly typed to an Enumeration of type Product and your view will always expect an enumeration of typ Product. The error you are getting here is because you are passing a single Product object which does not match with the type of the View.

If you want to stick with `IEnumeratble<product>`, you might want to create a list of products in Controller or in your TypeListOf() method and pass it to View.